# Server process running on Indy10 partially stops responding when OnConnect event interacts with a TTabControls Tabs from another form in Lazarus

Tags: networking, tcp, tabcontrol, lazarus, indy10

Tried to describe most of my problem in the title, and I mostly did.

Basically, I've made my own little TCP Server with Indy 10 in Lazarus. All it does is it accepts packets in form of bytes that contain a certain `char` representing a letter from English alphabet. I'm reading these bytes with the `Context`s' `IOHandler` like this:

```
procedure TServerSideForm.OnExecuteServer(Context: TIdContext);
var
  IO: TIdIOHandler;
  keyPressed: char;
begin
  //
  IO := Context.Connection.IOHandler;

  if not(IO.InputBufferIsEmpty) then
  begin
    LogForm.LogToForm('Recieving a packet from ' + Context.Binding.IP + '(' + Context.Binding.PeerIP + ')');

    keyPressed := IO.ReadChar;
    AddKeyToAppropriateClient(keyPressed, Context.Binding.IP);
  end;

  IndySleep(10);
  //
end;
```

And this works perfectly.

However, I've got another form that has a `TTabControl` in it, which has a tab for each user connected to my server, there is also a `TMemo` in each tab. Tabs and memos are created at runtime and the function that does that, does not throw any exceptions.

Here's how the `AddTab()` function from my other form looks like (for creating tabs and memos described above):

```
procedure TConnectionsForm.AddTab(IP: string);
var
  newMemo: TMemo;
begin
  ConnectionTabs.Tabs.Add(IP);
  currTabIndx := ConnectionTabs.TabIndex;

  newMemo := TMemo.Create(ConnectionsForm);

  newMemo.AnchorSide[akTop].Side:=asrTop;
  newMemo.AnchorSide[akTop].Control:=ConnectionTabs;
  newMemo.BorderSpacing.Top:=2;

  newMemo.AnchorSide[akBottom].Side:=asrBottom;
  newMemo.AnchorSide[akBottom].Control:=ConnectionTabs;
  newMemo.BorderSpacing.Bottom:=2;

  newMemo.AnchorSide[akLeft].Side:=asrLeft;
  newMemo.AnchorSide[akLeft].Control:=ConnectionTabs;
  newMemo.BorderSpacing.Left:=2;

  newMemo.AnchorSide[akRight].Side:=asrRight;
  newMemo.AnchorSide[akRight].Control:=ConnectionTabs;
  newMemo.BorderSpacing.Right:=2;

  newMemo.Anchors := [akTop, akBottom, akLeft, akRight];

  newMemo.Parent := ConnectionTabs;
  newMemo.Visible:=true;

  newMemo.Lines.Add(IP);

  SetLength(connectionMessagesArr, Length(connectionMessagesArr)+1);
  connectionMessagesArr[Length(connectionMessagesArr)-1] := newMemo;

  ShowOnly(currTabIndx);
end;
```

It seems to be working fine, I've tested it multiple times on its own.

But when I run that function from my `OnConnect` function for my `TIdTCPServer` the server process seems to freeze until some other event, like `OnExecute`, for example, happens. When `OnExecute` does execute, the messages that have been accepted by the process are also executed. For example, if my program freezes, and while it's frozen, I will try to minimize one of my forms and move some other form somewhere else on the screen, they will do that after the program unfreezes.

Here's my own `OnConnect` function:

```
procedure TServerSideForm.OnConnectServer(Context: TIdContext);
begin
  LogForm.LogToForm(Context.Binding.IP + ' has connected to the server (' + Context.Binding.PeerIP + ')');

  //ConnectionsForm.AddTab(Context.Binding.PeerIP); // Boom
  //ConnectionsForm.ConnectionTabs.Tabs.Add('!!'); // Boom
end;
```

As I've also stated in the title, any kind of interaction with `TTabControl`s tabs makes the program freeze. `ConnectionsForm.ConnectionTabs.Tabs.Add('!!');` also makes the program freeze (here, `ConnectionsTabs` is my `TTabControl` variable inside my form called `ConnectionsForm`).

I really have no idea to what is going on in here, so some help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I've done a little bit more testing. It appears that most of the runtime form-manipulations of my secondary `ConnectionsForm` cause a freeze.

Comment: Another thing, I'm new to using Indy10 and I'm guessing something is not thread-safe in my code. As I've read on other sources, accessing UI elements in `OnSomething` events is not thread-safe. So I have to synchronize my function calls somehow, but what is the best way in my situation?

Comment: `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, its events run in worker threads, so you MUST synchronize with the main UI thread when touching the GUI.  You can use Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class for that (in this situation, I would use `TIdNotify` instead of `TIdSync`, since there is no need for the thread to wait on the UI to return), or use FPC's `TThread.Synchonize()` or `TThread.Queue()` method.

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't be using `InputBufferIsEmpty` in the manner you showed. Call `ReadChar` unconditionally, let it block until a character actually arrives, then do the rest of your code: `procedure TServerSideForm.OnExecuteServer(Context: TIdContext); var keyPressed: char; begin keyPressed := Context.Connection.IOHandler.ReadChar; LogForm.LogToForm('Recieving a packet from ' + Context.Binding.IP + '(' + Context.Binding.PeerIP + ')'); AddKeyToAppropriateClient(keyPressed, Context.Binding.IP); end;` Just make sure `LogToForm()` and `AddKeyToAppropriateClient()` are thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the information @RemyLebeau. I've already made several changes to my program since I posted this question, some of do include using `TThread`s. And my functions are thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, my program was really thread-unsafe.

Solved the problem by adding my little Sync class:

```
type
  TMySync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    context: TIdContext;
  end;
```

And doing all my `TTabControl` shenanigans in its `DoSyncronize` overridden function.

```
procedure TMySync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  LogForm.LogToForm(Context.Binding.IP + ' has connected to the server (' + Context.Binding.PeerIP + ')');

  ConnectionsForm.AddTab(Context.Binding.PeerIP);
end;
```

And `OnConnect` has been changed to:

```
procedure TServerSideForm.OnConnectServer(Context: TIdContext);
var
  sync: TMySync;
begin
//
  sync := TMySync.Create;
  try
    sync.context := Context;
    sync.Synchronize;
  finally
    Sync.Free;
  end;
end;
```

P.S.
Did an analogous this to my `OnDisconnect` function.

Everything seems to work for now.